# Arabic site search not working online

Tags: php, post, arabic

I've created a simple site search and I am using the following code

```
 <form  id="search" name="form1" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" />
 <input id="sitesearch" name="sitesearch" type="text" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
 <input name="search" id="search" type="submit" />
 </form>
```

on my local server it works ok an I can see on url bar
    search.php?sp=العلامة%20البيضاء
on my online server though I get
    search?sp=%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B1%25D9%2586%25D8%...
On the online the weired thing is that I get the correct results on IE9 but not on Chrome and Firefox

Anyoe has a clue?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the search before sending it to the server?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of encoding . It is not converting to `utf8`.

Use `utf8_encode` for encoding the text and use `utf8_decode` for decoding.

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini on the server

find 
`; http://php.net/default-charset`

replaced withe

```
; http://php.net/default-charset
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

---

add to your file on head

```
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

---

### and your file save as use utf-8 encoding

change your browser withe safari or chrome to be right  100% متأكد